# How to access items in a JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax, get

I have an AJAX GET that returns an array that looks like the following:

```
{
“periodStart” : “2016-10-09T06:00:00Z", 
“periodEnd":"2016-10-16T06:00:00Z",
“nextPageStart":null,
“prevPageStart":"2016-10-02T00:00:00Z",
“period":"WEEKLY",
“powerInfo":null,
“totalSavings":
5.8863351343078,

“savings”:[
{
“maxTemperature":75,
“acRunSeconds":16432,
“savedRunSeconds":3266,
“kwhSaved":60.342324672236224,
”periodStart":"2016-10-09T06:00:00Z",
“savedMoney":1.5085581168059057,
“normalMoneyCost”:1.6226692279170167,
“periodName":"Sunday"
},
{
“maxTemperature":74,
“acRunSeconds":6822
,”savedRunSeconds":5657,
“kwhSaved":76.18189032209128,
“periodStart":"2016-10-10T06:00:00Z",
“savedMoney":1.904547258052282,
“normalMoneyCost":1.951922258052282,
“periodName":"Monday"
},
{
“maxTemperature":62,
“acRunSeconds":9311,
“savedRunSeconds":12,
“kwhSaved":28.03764418071857
,”periodStart”:"2016-10-11T06:00:00Z",
“savedMoney":0.7009411045179643,
“normalMoneyCost":0.7656008267401866,
“periodName":"Tuesday"
},
{
“maxTemperature":78,
“acRunSeconds":11275,
“savedRunSeconds":1431,
“kwhSaved":34.191927009102564,
“periodStart":"2016-10-12T06:00:00Z",
“savedMoney":0.8547981752275642,
“normalMoneyCost":0.9330967863386753,
“periodName":"Wednesday"
},
{
“maxTemperature":78,
“acRunSeconds":17967,
“savedRunSeconds":11864,
“kwhSaved":26.880751977008043,
“periodStart":"2016-10-13T06:00:00Z",
“savedMoney":0.6720187994252012
,”normalMoneyCost":0.7967896327585345,
“periodName":"Thursday"
},
{
“maxTemperature":78,
“acRunSeconds":7649,
“savedRunSeconds”:2008,
“kwhSaved":4.5674527454968805,
“periodStart":"2016-10-14T06:00:00Z",
“savedMoney":0.11418631863742201,
“normalMoneyCost":0.16730437419297756,
“periodName”:"Friday"
},
{
"maxTemperature":73,
“acRunSeconds":6174,
“savedRunSeconds":1876,
“kwhSaved":5.251414465658444,
“periodStart":"2016-10-15T06:00:00Z",
“savedMoney":0.1312853616414611,
“normalMoneyCost”0.1741603616414611,
“periodName":"Saturday"
}
],
“temperatureUnit":"F",
“currency":
{
“name":"USD",
“symbol":"$"
}
}
```

How do I grab individual values from the array?
For instance if I wanted to return the value “1.5085581168059057" for the "savedMoney" heading in the array and set it equal to the following variable:

`var savings_graph1 = 1.5085581168059057`

How would I do this? I assume I would have to loop through the array and find it but every time I try I get "undefined" or [object Object] errors.

The end goal is to place that number into a graph and plot savings; I just can't seem to get the correct number from the array into a variable so I can use it in my JavaScript.

The number from the array will be placed into the .data() field in the following D3.js that will graph the number on a chart.

```
vizs[0]
    .data(280)                              // current value
    .min(0)                                 // min value
    .max(100)                               // max value
    .capRadius(1)                           // Sets the curvature of the ends of the arc.
    .startAngle(250)                        // Angle where progress bar starts
    .endAngle(110)                          // Angle where the progress bar stops
    .arcThickness(.12)                      // The thickness of the arc (ratio of radius)
    .label(function (d,i) {                 // The 'label' property allows us to use a dynamic function for labeling.
        return d3.format("$,.2f")(d);
    });

vizs[1]
    .data(550)                              // current value
    .min(0)                                 // min value
    .max(200)                               // max value
    .capRadius(1)                           // Sets the curvature of the ends of the arc.
    .startAngle(210)
    .endAngle(150)
    .arcThickness(.07)
    .label(function (d,i) { return d3.format(".0f")(d); });

vizs[2]
    .data(820)                              // current value
    .min(0)                                 // min value
    .max(300)                               // max value
    .capRadius(1)                           // Sets the curvature of the ends of the arc.
    .startAngle(180)
    .endAngle(180)
    .arcThickness(.04)
    .label(function (d,i) { return d3.format(".0f")(d) + "%"; });
```

The end result will be as follows: AJAX GET request completed, data is taken from the array and sent to a variable, variable is used in the D3 code and data is then plotted on a graph for the end user. If anyone knows how to get the data from the array to a Javascript variable I would be greatly appreciative.

The AJAX request looks like the following:

```
function getSavings() {

    var baseUrl = $('#stage_select').find(":selected").val();

    $('#date-output').html("UTC date now: " + moment.utc().format());

    var url = baseUrl + "/savings/acunits/{acid}/random";

    var username = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    var data = {"email" : username , "password" : password};
    $('#output').append("request " + url + "\n");
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        processData: false,
        async: true,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader ('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password));
        },
        success: function (res) {
            $('#output').append("response -> " + JSON.stringify(res) + "\n\n");
        },
        error: function (jqxhr) {
            $('#output').append("response " + JSON.stringify(jqxhr.responseText) + "\n\n");
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: I tried that solution and it returned "undefined."

Comment: You can use `result.savings[0].savedMoney`, where `result` is your AJAX response

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'savedMoney' of undefined"

sorry last message cut off**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

The array needed eval as follows:

```
var all =  eval("(function(){return " + array + ";})()");
```

once that was done `alert(all.savings[0].savedMoney);` worked.

Thanks Jaco, your answer was closest.

The complete AJAX call looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    processData: false,
    async: true,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader ('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password));
    },
    success: function (res) {
    $('#output').append(JSON.stringify(res));
    var firstDivContent = document.getElementById('output');
    var array = firstDivContent.innerHTML;
    var all =  eval("(function(){return " + array + ";})()");
    alert(all.savings[0].savedMoney);

    },
    error: function (jqxhr) {
        $('#output').append("response " + JSON.stringify(jqxhr.responseText) + "\n\n");
    },
});
```